# Videos play one after other

Tags: video, mp4, playlist

I have some mp4 videos uploaded in my host. (1_1.mp4, 1_2.mp4, 1_3.mp4...) I want the videos play one after other.

I wonder if there is some kind of JS that i can use.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

The following page offers a comparison list with the most popular free HTML5 players http://praegnanz.de/html5video/. You can see which of them support playlists and allow to play your mp4 files each after other.
If you are searching for an ASP.NET AJAX player check RadMediaPlayer: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/media-player/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx